# Cannot get item when crawl data using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I have inspected element from chrome:
[image]

I want to get data in the red box (can be more than one) using scrapy. I used this code (I see the tutorial from the scrapy documentation):

```
import scrapy

class KamusSetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "kamusset_spider"
    start_urls = ['http://kbbi.web.id/' + 'abad']

    def parse(self, response):
        for kamusset in response.css("div#d1"):
            text = kamusset.css("div.sub_17 b.tur.highlight::text").extract()
            print(dict(text=text))
```

But, there is no result:

[image]

What happen? I have change it to this(use splash) but still not working:

```
    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse, args={'wait': 0.5})

    def parse(self, response):
        html = response.body

        for kamusset in response.css("div#d1"):
            text = kamusset.css("div.sub_17 b.tur.highlight::text").extract()
            print(dict(text=text))
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case it seems that the page content is generated dynamically --
 eventhough you can see the elements present when inspecting from browser, they are not present in the HTML source (i.e. in what Scrapy sees). That's because Scrapy can't render JavaScript etc. You need to use some kind of browser to render the page and then put the result to Scrapy for processing. I recommend using [Splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) for it's seamless integration with Scrapy.

Comment: So, how to use it?

Comment: I think that is not working. I have changed my code but the result is still null. I have attached my code above.

Comment: Do you have Splash set up, or you just changed the code of your spider?

Comment: I just run pip install scrapy-splash and change my code.

Comment: You have to have running instance of Splash, see [documentation](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html) for how to install. The easiest way to go is with Docker. `scrapy-splash` is just a Python API for integrating Splash with Scrapy. Also, you have to change the `settings.py` as noted in the `scrapy-splash` documentation.

Comment: Where is I can find settings.py?

Comment: In the project directory, see [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#creating-a-project)

Comment: I don't have a project. I just use a python file script.

Comment: OK, there are other ways how to specify settings, again, see the [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#populating-the-settings). I'd go with `custom_settings` attribute inside the spider class.